# Proving solution behavior of a 2x2 system of ODEs with arbitrary real constant coefficients (given trace and determinant conditions)

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of differential equations:

**x**'<sub>1</sub> = a**x**<sub>1</sub> + b**x**<sub>2</sub>

**x**'<sub>2</sub> = c**x**<sub>1</sub> + d**x**<sub>2</sub>

where a, b, c, and d are arbitrary real numbers. I have an iff statement I'm looking to prove: Show that all solutions approach 0 as t approaches infinity if, and only if, Tr(A) < 0 and Det(A) > 0, where A is the 2x2 coefficient matrix of the system.

Proving that all solutions approach 0 if Tr(A) < 0 and Det(A) > 0, I've made a little progress and understand the intuition. There would be two cases - where the discriminant is negative, so the eigenvalues are complex, and where the discriminant is positive, so the eigenvalues are real. If they're real, I need to show that they're negative, but I'm having trouble doing so. As for the complex, I'm hoping I'm correct in assuming that I only need to focus on the real part because the complex part would just be sinusoidal and this would simply be trivial (tr(A) < 0).

How can I show that, in the case of real eigenvalues, Tr(A), a+d, will be larger in absolute value than the square root of the discriminant, therefore making the numerator in the quadratic formula negative and thus the eigenvalues negative?

As for proving the other way, that if solutions approach 0 as t approaches infinity then Tr(A) must be < 0 and Det(A) must be > 0, any tips on getting started? Should be able to make headway if I can get the intuition there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace is the sum of the eigenvalues and the determinant is their product.
  I suggest doing the proof in two steps:

1. Show that the condition on trace and determinant is equivalent to: all eigenvalues have negative real part.
2. Show that all eigenvalues have negative real part iff all solutions go to $0$.

Some hints:

In the case of (non-real) complex eigenvalues, they are complex conjugates so their product is positive, and their real parts are both equal to half the trace.

Note that the real and imaginary parts of complex solutions of the system are solutions.

If the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are distinct, then all solutions are
$c_1 u_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} + c_2 u_2 e^{\lambda_2 t}$ where $u_1$ and $u_2$ are eigenvectors.  But 
the case of a repeated eigenvalue needs to be considered as well.