# Find the range of values of $a$ such that $|u(t)|\to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

consider the initial value problem $u'(t)=Au(t),t>0$ and $u(0)=u_0$
. Where $u_0$ is given vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 \\ 
 1&a 
\end{bmatrix}$$
Find the range of values of $a$  such that $|u(t)|\to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.

***My idea:-***

the characteristic equation of $A$ is $\begin{vmatrix}
1-\lambda &-2 \\ 
 1& a- \lambda
\end{vmatrix}=0$

then $\lambda ^2- \lambda (a+1)+(2+a)=0$

$\Rightarrow  \lambda=\frac{a+1\pm \sqrt{(a+1)^2-4(a+2)}}{2}$

from here i am stuck

Comment: **Hint:** When would a system go to zero as $t \to \infty$ (what do the eigenvalues need to be)? Consider negative eigenvalues or imaginary eigenvalues with negative real part. How can you find that for the expression you derived? Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018793/proving-solution-behavior-of-a-2x2-system-of-odes-with-arbitrary-real-constant-c

Comment: You might also like to try the approach based on section $23.4$ of https://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/~novozhil/Teaching/266%20Data/lecture_23.pdf using the trace and determinant approach and this handy summary: http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/critical.html

Answer (score 1):

For $|u(t)| \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$, eigen values of $A$ must have a negative real part. Now, eigen value of $A$ are given by $$\lambda = \frac{(a+1)-\sqrt{(1-a)^2 - 8}}{2}$$ So we must have $$a+1 < 0 \implies a < -1 \qquad$$ and if $\sqrt{(1-a)^2 - 8}$ is real, then we must have $$\lambda < 0 \implies (a+1)< \sqrt{(1-a)^2 - 8} \implies (a+1)^2 < (1-a)^2-8 \implies a > -2 $$
So $-2 < a < -1$.